# Error in connecting CMake to FreeBASIC compiler. CMake Error: The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: command-line, compiling, cmake

I was in the middle of installing Allegro to help me compile C++ games and animations. I needed to install a Make program to get the ball rolling. I installed CMake and tried to connect it to my FreeBASIC compiler. I have the CMake file inside the FreeBASIC files and try to get them to talk. I used this command, which came with the instructions on how to install CMake
`$ cmake ..`

But that didn't work. I got the following error

`CMake Error: The source directory "/home/miesrah/Downloads/FreeBASIC-0.90.1-linux/cmake-2.8.12.2-Linux-i386" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.`

So i used another command.

`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..`

And I got a different error

`CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefiles`

What could these errors mean, what command should I be using, and what other steps must i take to install Allegro and Cmake?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the allegro development files:

```
sudo apt-get install liballegro5-dev
```

Then include the allegro headers in your source file.